# Issues with Path, installing packages, Conda environments, and several built-in commands

Tags: python-3.x, windows, matplotlib, anaconda

I've recently upgraded my PC with various bits and pieces and installed Windows 10 Pro. Most of what I do is data science related, but that's irrelevant.

I've had several issues with Anaconda 3 installations, my Path variables, installing various packages, and several Windows commands that I understood to be built-in:

- Obviously, virtual environments are popular, and I've been using conda environments to run basic code without issue, however, several very key libraries are giving me issues when I try to install them. The first one I ran into an issue with was the very standard and presumably easy-to-install `matplotlib`, however, the issue I ran into here and am still getting is that `chcp is not recognized as an internal or external command...`. When I run `where chcp` **as admin** I have no issues. `chcp` will run without error as well, but as soon as stop `cmd` as admin, `chcp` nor `where` commands work whatsoever. I don't get it. I've done just about everything I can to the Path variable that I've seen online, and nothing has worked. Uninstalled and reinstalled. Nothing has changed.

  Furthermore, isn't Anaconda supposed to come pre-installed with these?

**note** `where` does not return an error that would indicate that it's looking in the wrong directory; I get an exit code DNE 0 due to the command apparently not existing outside of admin privileges in `\System32`. Makes no sense to me and haven't found anything like this/ a vague resemblance of a solution elsewhere.

So with all of that in mind:

- what might be causing this issue? Permissions? Locations? Something I'm missing from the Path variables? etc. Fixing the issue with `chcp` should do it for me.
- How can I get the Anaconda "package" to, well, work? -> I can get the launcher, Jupyter notebooks, etc., but what I'm referring to here is the set of packages for Python itself -- that's why I went for Anaconda to begin with.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney in OP I don't mention anything about it but I run into the same issues as when I run the commands without admin. OP is only referring to the basic Windows CMD and then CMD run with admin privileges.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney No, I am not. Commands wise, nearly everything I've been running has been in the admin-privileged terminal. As I said, though, I have run them from the Anaconda prompt to test it out and run into the same issue: ```where``` is not recognized.... ```chcp``` is not recognized.